# Display data of the current user in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display the trips saved by the current user. However, the app displayed every trip that is in the database even the ones that does not have the same uid as the current user. How do I fix this?

Here is the data saved in firestore:

[image: trip database]

below is how I grab the information:

```
Future getTrip() async{
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('trip')
  .where("userid", isEqualTo: user?.uid)
  .orderBy('date', descending: false)
  .orderBy('time', descending: false)
  .get()
  .then((ds) {
  ds.docs.forEach((data) {
    var tempList = {
      'dest': data['destination'],
      'desc': data['description'],
      'image': data['image'],
      'time': data['time'],
      'date': data['date'],
      'doc': data.id,
    };
    setState(() {
      trips.add(tempList);
    });
  });
});
```

}

Then this is how I display my data:

```
trips.isNotEmpty ? ListView.builder(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: trips.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index){
          return Column(
            children: [
              Card(
                child: ListTile(
                leading: Image.network("${trips.elementAt(index)['image']}",fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,),
                title: Text("${trips.elementAt(index)['date']}"),
                subtitle: Text("${trips.elementAt(index)['dest']}\n${trips.elementAt(index)['time']}"),
                trailing:Wrap(
                  spacing: 5,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap:(){
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditTrip(trip: trips[index])),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.edit,color: Colors.lightBlue)
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap:(){
                        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('trip').doc('${trips.elementAt(index)['doc']}')
                        .delete()
                        .then((value) {
                          setState(() {
                            trips.removeAt(index);
                          });
                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                            msg:'Trip Deleted',
                          );
                        }
                        ).catchError((e) => Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Error updating document $e"));
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.delete,color: Colors.red)
                    ),
                  ]
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ]
          );
        },
      )
      :Text('Your Itinerary is Empty...', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practice: Display data from Firebase in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625819/best-practice-display-data-from-firebase-in-flutter)

Comment: Are you saying that your query returns documents from other users, even when you have the `.where("userid", isEqualTo: user?.uid)` clause in there? That seems very unexpected.

Comment: Your `.orderBy()` functions won't work too. Try to order by your self date `["14/9/2022", "28/11/2022", "30/1/2022"]` using dart language.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes, unfortunately. I'm also confused.

Comment: @Mises well fortunately this one works, I just can't get the current user's data only

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've never seen Firestore return documents that did not meet the conditions on the query I gave it. You might want to try and reproduce the problem in a simpler example, without the additional fields and without any UI (just printing the resulting data). If you start from scratch and still get the same results, share an update [repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).